# Invisible mailto: in org mode email links?

Tags: emacs, email, org-mode

Out of the box in Emacs Org Mode, an email address `example@example.com` is not linked.

`mailto:example@example.com` is a working link but is ugly.

`[[mailto:example@example.com][example@example.com]]` is an invisible `mailto` link because it shows only `example@example.com` but works like a normal `mailto` link.

**How can I make all email addresses invisible mailto links?**

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish that automatically, you'd need to mess with the regexp matching inside of org.el.  Specifically, looking quickly, it looks like you need to modify at least the *org-make-link-regexps* function.  But out of the box, org-mode won't do this without some coding help.